# duplicate data with scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I 'm trying to get the tittle, author, link, ISSN/ISBN and year of the publications found on this website:

http://eprints.bbk.ac.uk/view/subjects/csis.html

with the following code:

```
def parse_web6(self, response): #Eprints BBK
    i=0
    for sel in response.xpath("//div/div[@class='ep_tm_page_content']/div[@class='ep_view_page ep_view_page_view_subjects']"):
        publicaciones = sel.xpath("//div/div[@class='ep_tm_page_content']/div[@class='ep_view_page ep_view_page_view_subjects']/p/a/text()").extract() #publicacion
        autores = response.xpath("//div/div[@class='ep_tm_page_content']/div[@class='ep_view_page ep_view_page_view_subjects']/p/span[@class='person_name']/text()").extract() #Autor
        links = sel.xpath("//div/div[@class='ep_tm_page_content']/div[@class='ep_view_page ep_view_page_view_subjects']/p/a/@href").extract()
        if i == 0:
            o=0
            while o != len(publicaciones):
                publicacion = PublicacionItem()
                publicacion['titulo_publicacion'] = publicaciones[o]
                publicacion['anio_publicacion'] = response.xpath("//div/div[@class='ep_tm_page_content']/div[@class='ep_view_page ep_view_page_view_subjects']/p").re(r'\d\d\d\d')[0].strip() #Fecha, ultimos cuatro digitos.
                publicacion['isbn'] = response.xpath("//div/div[@class='ep_tm_page_content']/div[@class='ep_view_page ep_view_page_view_subjects']/p").re(r'\d\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d')[0].strip()
                publicacion['nombre_autor'] = autores[o]
                publicacion['url_link'] = links[o]
                yield publicacion
                o+=1
            i+=1
```

Which works, but for some reason , both the year as the ISSN/ISBN are always the same:

[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HrG1.png)

In addition to this problem, as you can see , the ISBN/ISSN has different format in some publications,or even have none, ¿how I can define the XPath to work with all formats?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using absolute XPath expressions on `sel` which is already a selected element from another absolute XPath expression (`//...`).
This means they will select the same elements all the time for each iteration, and not relatively to `sel`.

Relative XPath expressions (`.//...`) are the way to go in loops like that. This is the first thing to fix.

As a bonus, and to illustrate, here's a commented and simple spider doing what you need (I think).

```
import scrapy

class PublicationSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'pubspider'
    start_urls = ('http://eprints.bbk.ac.uk/view/subjects/csis.html',)

    def parse(self, response):

        # each publication is within a <p> element, let's loop on those
        for publication in response.css('div > div.ep_tm_page_content > div.ep_view_page.ep_view_page_view_subjects > p'):

            # the publication title is inside a <a> link, which also contains a URL
            for title in publication.xpath('./a'):
                pubtitle = title.xpath('normalize-space(.)').extract_first()
                publink = title.xpath('@href').extract_first()
                break
            # use a regex to find year digits inside brackets
            pubyear = publication.xpath('./text()').re_first(r'\((\d+)\)')

            # get text nodes from <span> before the link
            authors = publication.xpath('./span[@class="person_name"][./following-sibling::a]/text()').extract()

            # get text nodes after the link and use a regex matching either ISBN or ISSN,
            # get first result with re_first()
            # this can be an empty list is there no ISxN
            isxn = publication.xpath('./a/following-sibling::text()').re_first(r'(ISBN\s+\d+|ISSN\s+\d+-\d+)')
            yield {
                'title': pubtitle,
                'link': publink,
                'year':  pubyear,
                'authors': authors,
                'isxn': isxn
            }
```

You can run this spider with `scrapy runspider`:

```
$ scrapy runspider 35185701.py 
2016-02-03 22:16:25 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.4 started (bot: scrapybot)
2016-02-03 22:16:26 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://eprints.bbk.ac.uk/view/subjects/csis.html> (referer: None)
2016-02-03 22:16:26 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://eprints.bbk.ac.uk/view/subjects/csis.html>
{'authors': [u'Adam, S.P.', u'Karras, D.A.', u'Magoulas, George D.', u'Vrahatis, M.N.'], 'year': u'2014', 'link': u'http://eprints.bbk.ac.uk/13757/', 'isxn': u'ISSN 0893-6080', 'title': u'Solving the linear interval tolerance problem for weight initialization of neural networks.'}
...
2016-02-03 22:16:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://eprints.bbk.ac.uk/view/subjects/csis.html>
{'authors': [u'Zuccon, G.', u'Azzopardi, L.', u'Zhang, Dell', u'Wang, J.'], 'year': u'2012', 'link': u'http://eprints.bbk.ac.uk/7099/', 'isxn': u'ISBN 9783642289965', 'title': u'Top-k retrieval using facility location analysis.'}
2016-02-03 22:16:27 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2016-02-03 22:16:27 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 238,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 434181,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 3, 21, 16, 27, 657239),
 'item_scraped_count': 794,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 796,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 3, 21, 16, 25, 985416)}
2016-02-03 22:16:27 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: this works perfect! But does not save the authors in the database. Perhaps because I have to iterate over authors before the yield? Authors and Publications have a many-to-many relationship with an intermediate table.

Comment: The code I shared extracts a list of authors for a publication. If you need to save authors and publications in a relational database you'll need to iterate over authors list at some point, maybe in an item pipeline. You can also yield 1 item for the publication, and N items, 1 item per author, keeping a key for the publication (the URL perhaps) and build the many to many relationships afterwards. It really depends on how you are doing it right now, worth another question on stack overflow

Answer (score 0):

After the part with `if i == 0:` you do not need to do repeat the xpath on publicationes response anymore, but on the result that you got stored in publicationes array. So don't apply regex on: `publicacion['anio_publicacion'] = response.xpath("//div...`, but on `publicacion['anio_publicacion'] = publicaciones[o]...` , as you declare iterator but you don't use it for publications. In similar fasion I would suggest you build also an array for your years and then iterate over it - here you did not build the iterator, so you cannot really apply it.

Try to get rid of your repetition, your code will be easier to read, follow and correct.There is much too much repetition going on so you can easily get frustrated. Other hint, you do not need to start looking for xpath from the root of the document, which will make it shorter and again easier to debug (start using `//` and `./` expressions in xpath). So e.g.:you could declare right at the start:

```
storedResponse = response.xpath("//div[@class='ep_view_page ep_view_page_view_subjects']")
```

and then do e.g.:

```
for sel in storedResponse:
    publicaciones = sel.xpath("./p/a/text()").extract() #publicacion
```

If you treat ISBN and ISSN in the same way, be careful because this regex with a dash will only work for your ISSN not ISBN `(r'\d\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d')`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! but when i run it i get:  publicacion['nombre_autor'] = autores[o]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: I use this (with the storedResponse) autores = response.xpath("./p/span[@class='person_name']/text()").extract()